# Кириллица в пути к файлу

Tags: python

Подскажите, почему я не могу открыть файл `Excel`?

```
file = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Home-PC\Desktop\Иван\Книга1.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист3')
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

> File "", line 1
>       file = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Home-PC\Desktop\Иван\Книга1.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист3')
>
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX
>   escape

Проблема в кириллице в пути к файлу? Если да, то как ее решить? Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте перед строкой-путем `r`. `r'C:\Users\...'`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить обратный слеш `\` на обычный `/`.
`Python` воспринимает `\U` как управляющий символ (наравне с `\n`, `\t`, `\r` и др.).

***Пример:***

```py
file = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Home-PC/Desktop/Иван/Книга1.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист3')
```

Comment: спасибо. помогло

Answer (score 0):

заменил слэш на обратный - все заработало.
но теперь столкнулся с другой проблемой.
почему не открывается файл `.csv`?

вот код

```
`id_liquidation = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Home-PC/Desktop/Иван/DICT_UL_LIQUIDATION_STATUS.csv', sep='\t')`
```

вот ошибка

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 0: invalid continuation byte**

Comment: Вы знаете кодировку файла? Если да, то укажите её в аргументе `encoding`, например так: `encoding='utf-8'` (даже если не знаете, попробуйте `utf-8`). Если не получится, то можно пересохранить файл в нужной кодировке или попробовать `cp1252` с `ISO-8859-1`, к примеру.

Comment: Не стоит задавать новый вопрос в поле для ответа на старый. Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос, нажав кнопку править под ним, или, что ещё лучше, задать новый, так как они не сильно взаимосвязаны. А ответ, который Вам помог, можно принять, нажав на зелёную галочку слева от него.